# Vertical-align middle not working in a table

Tags: html, css

I am trying to vertically align the text inside of the table cell however it is not working. It currently shows the text in mobile as shown in the picture below. The problem only exist in mobile.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YTPi.png) vs [How I want it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPRO8.png)

[DCR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiXl0.png)

```html
<table width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;"><strong>&nbsp;Estimated Delivery Times</strong></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 26.2704%; text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;">United States</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 31.7604%;vertical-align: middle;"><span>3 - 6 business days</span></td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 39.2015%;vertical-align: middle;"><span>7 - 13 business days</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 26.2704%; text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;">Canada</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 31.7604%;vertical-align: middle;"><span>5 - 11 business days</span></td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 39.2015%;vertical-align: middle;"><span>7 - 15 business days</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 26.2704%; text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;">United Kingdom</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 31.7604%;vertical-align: middle;"><span>7 - 10 business days</span></td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 39.2015%;vertical-align: middle;"><span>7 - 12 business days</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 26.2704%; text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;">Australia</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 31.7604%;vertical-align: middle;"><span>3 - 6 business days</span></td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 39.2015%;vertical-align: middle;"><span>7 - 15 business days</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 26.2704%; text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;">New Zealand</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 31.7604%;vertical-align: middle;"><span>6 - 11 business days</span></td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 39.2015%;vertical-align: middle;"><span>7 - 15 business days</span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: There is no `vertical-align` in the code sample.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry I meant to say that I tried vertical-align in each td and it didn't work

Comment: Please could you put up a snippet which shows the problem when you use vertical-align, for example we need to see how you are applying it.

Comment: can you post a sketch or image of how you want it to look?

Comment: I edited the snippet to reflect how I was using the vertical-align

Comment: great, but how do you want it to look?

Comment: I added a screenshot of how I wanted it to look

Comment: With the code in your snippet all texts are vertically middle-aligned, as you are asking for (?).

Comment: make the width of the 2nd and third columns the same

Comment: @Johannes yes that is what I want however on mobile it is not vertically aligned in the middle, it's kind of like a staircase as shown in the screenshot

Comment: No, it really works. Could it be that you have additional linebreaks in the example whose picture you posted? It looks as if there's an empty line before the text in every first td and an empty line after the text in every last td...

Comment: Try to add this in your css, if you have one. ``td {
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(50%);
  }

Comment: @DCR unfortunately the problem still persists when making the second and third row the same width

Comment: no it doesn't.  see snippet below

Comment: @DCR I replaced my snippet with your snippet, but I had to manually add the height for td on the chrome console. The problem unfortunately is still there. Please check the screenshot I edited into the post.

Comment: the problem is with the css you are now adding to the problem.  Learn how to ask a question on stackoverflow.  If you don't provide the code we can't help you.  Notice that it works fine in the snippet

Answer (score 0):

just make the width of 2nd and 3rd columns the same

```css
td{
height:15vh;
border:solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;"><strong>&nbsp;Estimated Delivery Times</strong></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 30%; text-align: center;">United States</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 35%;"><span>3 - 6 business days</span></td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 35%;"><span>7 - 13 business days</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 30%; text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;">Canada</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 35%;vertical-align: middle;"><span>5 - 11 business days</span></td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 35%;vertical-align: middle;"><span>7 - 15 business days</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 30%; text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;">United Kingdom</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 35%;vertical-align: middle;"><span>7 - 10 business days</span></td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 35%;vertical-align: middle;"><span>7 - 12 business days</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 30%; text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;">Australia</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 35%;vertical-align: middle;"><span>3 - 6 business days</span></td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 35%;vertical-align: middle;"><span>7 - 15 business days</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 30%; text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;">New Zealand</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 35%;vertical-align: middle;"><span>6 - 11 business days</span></td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 35%;vertical-align: middle;"><span>7 - 15 business days</span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```